# Use Tomcat and JIRA same time

Tags: tomcat, jira

I have Tomcat in my system(Unzipped. Not as a service). And I installed JIRA and created an issue there [using this link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/ATLAS/Dragons+Stage+1+-+Install+JIRA)

I have a Java web application, which is used to get URI, Issue Key, username and password values of JIRA in JSP. In the servlet I need to connect to JIRA and get the issue. But the problem is, only one service works at a time. When I run the Java web application in tomcat, I have to stop JIRA. So the servlet won't connect to JIRA.

Is there any possibility to use both at a time?

Comment: I'm guessing your JIRA is running on Tomcat, which is typical. So, in essence, you are trying to run two Tomcats at the same time. It is definitely possible to do this, by having the two use different ports. If your machine has multiple IP addresses, you can have them run on multiple IPs. You would have to change the Tomcat config: either the one under JIRA, or the other one.

Comment: Do you mean installing JIRA on tomcat? I didn't do that. I tried to change the pot number in tomcat/conf/server.xml. But still when I run tomcat server it is exiting because JIRA server is already started

Comment: JIRA runs on top of a web-server, like Tomcat. My guess is that your JIRA is running on a Tomcat that came packaged along with JIRA. Changing the Port numbers should do the trick, if you can change all the relevant numbers. In particular, change the Shutdown portnumber and the Port numbers being used by any Connectors that are defined in your server.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reckon your JIRA's Tomcat ports would need to be changed to reflect this:

1. Go to `$JIRA_INSTALL/conf/server.xml`
2. Search for `<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">`. Change **8005** to another port number (say, 8105).
3. Search for `<Connector port="8080"` and change **8080** to another port (say, port number 8180).
4. Restart JIRA.

You might need to change your Java application to reflect the port changes.